# How to plot multidimensional data in clusters

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataset that has 6497 instance, 12 attributes, and a class variable called q (quality). The class values can range from 3 to 9. The data can be downloaded in CSV format from [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/i2o6ywbdu2ws55k/wine_nocolor.csv)

I'm using k-mean to split the data into 3 clusters

```
set.seed(1234)
nr <- NROW(wine$.row)
ind <- sample(nr, 0.66 * nr, replace = FALSE) #66%
w_clus3 <- kmeans(wine[ind, 2:12], 3)
matrix3 <- table(cl_predict(w_clus3, wine[-ind,2:12 ]),wine$q[-ind])
```

Is there a way i can use clusplot or any other visual graph to show how the data was split among three clusters?

I tried but im getting errors.

```
clusplot(wine[2:12], w_clus3$cluster, color=TRUE, shade=TRUE,labels=2, lines=0)
```

If there are too many dimensions...how can I just show few attributes and how they were split in clusters.

Answer (score 1):

What about dimension reduction like [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)? Than you may have some visualizable feature set.